# В каком падеже

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: Руководством сельской библиотечной системы или системой. Ведь заведующий чем? А руководство чего? или чем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именно так: системы. Руководством (чего?)- библиотечной системы. Но: руководство(чем?) - библиотечной системой